# Simple neural network approximation the sine function

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to code a very simple neural network with 3 layers of neurons (3,3,1) and the rectified linear activation function to approximate the sine function in Python. My code runs through but the optimization I thought of does not seem to work as intended. I am fairly new to both, Python and neural networks. Could somebody give me some hints on how I could improve my optimization or maybe spots some other mistakes?

```
import numpy as np
import math as math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(123)
input = np.arange(0, 6.2, 0.1)

weights1 = np.random.rand(3,1)*2-[[1],[1],[1]]
weights2 = np.random.rand(3,3)*2-[[1],[1],[1]]
weights3 = np.random.rand(1,3)*2-[[1]]
biases1 = np.random.rand(3,1)*2-[[1],[1],[1]]
biases2 = np.random.rand(3,1)*2-[[1],[1],[1]]
bias3 = np.random.rand(1,1)*2-[[1]]

def layer1(input1, weights1, biases1) :
    return np.maximum([[0],[0],[0]],np.dot(weights1,input1)+biases1)

def layer2(input2, weights2, biases2) :
    return np.maximum([[0],[0],[0]],np.dot(weights2,input2)+biases2)

def layer3(input3, weights3, bias3) :
    return np.maximum([[0]],np.dot(weights3,input3)+bias3)
```

The optimization I thought of is just moving the weights and biases in the direction that decreases the mean squarred error of my input points.

```
delta = 0.0001
for i in range(1000):
    weights1_plus = weights1 + delta
    weights2_plus = weights2 + delta
    weights3_plus = weights3 + delta
    biases1_plus = biases1 + delta
    biases2_plus = biases2 + delta
    bias3_plus = bias3 + delta
    weights1_minus = weights1 - delta
    weights2_minus = weights2 - delta
    weights3_minus = weights3 - delta
    biases1_minus = biases1- delta
    biases2_minus = biases2 - delta
    bias3_minus = bias3 - delta
    
    mse_plus = 0
    mse_minus = 0
    for x in inputs :
        mse_plus += (math.sin(x)-layer3(layer2(layer1(x, weights1_plus, biases1), weights2, biases2), weights3, bias3))**2
        mse_minus += (math.sin(x)-layer3(layer2(layer1(x, weights1_minus, biases1), weights2, biases2), weights3, bias3))**2
    if mse_plus>mse_minus :
        weights1 = weights1 - 0.005
    else :
        weights1 = weights1 + 0.005
        
    mse_plus = 0
    mse_minus = 0
    for x in inputs :
        mse_plus += (math.sin(x)-layer3(layer2(layer1(x, weights1, biases1_plus), weights2, biases2), weights3, bias3))**2
        mse_minus += (math.sin(x)-layer3(layer2(layer1(x, weights1, biases1_minus), weights2, biases2), weights3, bias3))**2
    if mse_plus>mse_minus :
        biases1 = biases1 - 0.005
    else :
        biases1 = biases1 + 0.005
        
    mse_plus = 0
    mse_minus = 0
    for x in inputs :
        mse_plus += (math.sin(x)-layer3(layer2(layer1(x, weights1, biases1), weights2_plus, biases2), weights3, bias3))**2
        mse_minus += (math.sin(x)-layer3(layer2(layer1(x, weights1, biases1), weights2_minus, biases2), weights3, bias3))**2
    if mse_plus>mse_minus :
        weights2 = weights2 - 0.005
    else :
        weights2 = weights2 + 0.005
        
    mse_plus = 0
    mse_minus = 0
    for x in inputs :
        mse_plus += (math.sin(x)-layer3(layer2(layer1(x, weights1, biases1), weights2, biases2_plus), weights3, bias3))**2
        mse_minus += (math.sin(x)-layer3(layer2(layer1(x, weights1, biases1), weights2, biases2_minus), weights3, bias3))**2
    if mse_plus>mse_minus :
        biases2 = biases2 - 0.005
    else :
        biases2 = biases2 + 0.005
        
    mse_plus = 0
    mse_minus = 0
    for x in inputs :
        mse_plus += (math.sin(x)-layer3(layer2(layer1(x, weights1, biases1), weights2, biases2), weights3_plus, bias3))**2
        mse_minus += (math.sin(x)-layer3(layer2(layer1(x, weights1, biases1), weights2, biases2), weights3_minus, bias3))**2
    if mse_plus>mse_minus :
        weights3 = weights3 - 0.005
    else :
        weights3 = weights3 + 0.005
        
    mse_plus = 0
    mse_minus = 0
    for x in inputs :
        mse_plus += (math.sin(x)-layer3(layer2(layer1(x, weights1, biases1), weights2, biases2), weights3, bias3_plus))**2
        mse_minus += (math.sin(x)-layer3(layer2(layer1(x, weights1, biases1), weights2, biases2), weights3, bias3_minus))**2
    if mse_plus>mse_minus :
        bias3 = bias3 - 0.005
    else :
        bias3 = bias3 + 0.005
```

But if I plot my outcome function it looks really bad

```
test_inputs = np.arange(0, 6.2, 0.01)
test_outputs = []
for x in test_inputs :
    test_outputs.append(layer3(layer2(layer1(x,weights1, biases1),weights2, biases2),weights3, bias3))
test_outputs = [y[0][0] for y in test_outputs]
plt.plot(test_inputs, test_outputs)
```

[Image of the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jdFv.jpg)

Comment: TLDR: you need to implement backpropagation. Now, this code updates all weights at once. Instead, it should use prediction error to update the last layer weights, and calculate the delta in the last layer. Then, use this delta to update weights of the previous layer etc.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I have indeed read about backpropagation before but I don't really understand why just updating all weights at once does not lead anywhere.